# JMeter - Is it possible to run thread groups randomly but only one running at a time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to run load tests for 5 different req types with different number of users for each. At a time only one type of request should be hit with its defined no of users. The test should run for 24-48 hrs.

Is this possible to do this in jmeter? I am unable to randomize the thread groups for each request type with only one running at a time.

- Thread group 1 runs 10 thread per sec forever

  - Request 1
- Thread group 2 runs 5 thread per sec forever

  - Request 2
- Thread group 3 runs 4 thread per sec forever

  - Request 3
- Thread group 4 runs 2 thread per sec forever

  - Request 4
- Thread group 5 runs 1 thread per sec forever

  - Request 5

Thread group should run randomly and only one thread group should run at a time.

Please suggest if there is any other way to do this in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply the logical behavior at the "Thread Group" level. That is just not possible. Also, what you need does not seem to fit in the real world scenario unless you extend my knowledge with a valid use case.

Apart from randomizing the thread group you can do everything else mentioned and when you trigger the test all the thread groups will execute.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, Random controller picks one sampler at random from all those added under the same group and executes it. But my next step is running different no of users for each request type. How do it change the no of threads dynamically in that case.

Comment: Have you tried Marvok, https://www.se.informatik.uni-kiel.de/en/research/projects/markov4jmeter? It's a probability distribution method. So for example, if you have 100 users visiting the home page, 50 of them add products in the cart and 10 does the actual purchase. You can achieve this using Markov